# Update CouchDB document which hash slash in the doc id from C# code

Tags: .net, couchdb

I have create CouchDB database with documents that have slash (/) in the document ID.
I'm trying to update the database from C# code, I've try several CouchDB libs and also using plain-old-HttpWebRequest class but I fail with all because .NET Uri class escape the string pass into it.
I need to create a Uri like so:

```
http://myserver.com/db/firstpart%2Fsecondpart
```

which will always be escaped by .NET Uri class to

```
http://myserver.com/db/firstpart/secondpart
```

This cause CouchDB to treat the document content as attachment of document with ID firstpart instead of treat the document as content for document with id firstpart/secondpart.

Any ideas?

Comment: I like to use slash characters in my document IDs too. Everybody knows what it means, it is a very meaningful character. But if you have continued problems, perhaps switch to a different character such as `_` or `.` so you will avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you could encode the `%2f` part itself, so that .Net will decode it once, and then send the correctly-encoded version to the server?

The `%` character encodes as `%25`, therefore try this URL:

```
http://myserver.com/db/firstpart%252Fsecondpart
```

If that does work, maybe you could improve the code by calling [System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx).

A better solution would be to check the API to disable un-escaping. That feels like an API bug to me. If I tell the framework `one/two%2fthree` then what gives it the right to second-guess me? But that is the world of HTTP. (I hear that Apache httpd reverse-proxies are a nightmare with this.)

Comment: I'll try it, the problem is Uri class decode anything pass into the ctor and Microsoft remove the ctor that used to accept a parameter that signal not to decode the string passed into it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Would you please down-vote so that other people will know that this is **not** going to work? (I don't mind the reputation impact, nor the impact to my pride :)